# Ruby on Rails "target of repeat operator is not specified"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

An app I manage suddenly (after a reboot) shows the following error;

```
target of repeat operator is not specified: /\A\/(*hn)(?:\.([^\/.?]+))?\Z/
```

The code runs fine on my Macbook (development and production environments), yet on my server I'm seeing the above 500 message.

Here's the stack trace;

```
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/path/pattern.rb:94:in `accept'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/path/pattern.rb:177:in `to_regexp'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/path/pattern.rb:167:in `match'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:129:in `block in find_routes'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:128:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:128:in `find_all'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:128:in `find_routes'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:570:in `call'
sass (3.1.15) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__567979529779051348__call__4075940477208431972__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Found a buggy route entry.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server running the same version of Ruby that your development environment is? This is exactly what I'd expect to see if there was a version difference.

Comment: ## Local -->
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

## Production -->
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I'm installing 1.9.2-p180 on production now. :\

Comment: Nope .. I installed 1.9.2p180 and still have the same issue. Funny thing, we also have a "staging" VPS and the site works fine there. I have NFI what's going on. I've tried running on unicorn, webbrick, development / production - ALL PRODUCE THE SAME RESULT. Mind you, rails console works fine.